# Magento2 Tax not displaying in Cart Page

Tags: magento2, cart, tax

I am using Tax rule for some Countries, **Tax rate is displaying fine in Checkout page but in Cart page**, it is not displaying. I am using Custom Theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally Got it, we need to add below line in checkout_cart_index.xml file under Magento_Checkout/Layout in your theme Directory.

Find around line number 166

```
<item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
</item>
</item>

<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
</item>
</item>
```

Replace with

```
<item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
</item>
</item>

<item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/tax</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/tax</item>
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax</item>
</item>
</item>

<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
</item>
</item>
```

Comment: This doesnt worked.

Answer (score 3):

To add the tax value in the grand total of the cart page you must edit the grand-total.js file from:

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/

But you cannot edit this core file so you must copy it to:

> /app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/

and replace everything in grand-total.js with:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

After that run:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 1):

You are right now we can see tax value in total area but that tax is not added in total.

Subtotal    €13.63
Tax     €1.36
Order Total     €13.63

there Should be

Subtotal    €13.63
Tax     €1.36
Order Total     €14.99

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Change grand-total component in checkout_cart_index to Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total