# Magento2 order total is not showing tax value on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, tax

order total is not showing tax value on cart page. Even its working okay on checkout page. First tax was not showing on cart page, but after following below given process it start showing  on cart page but still order total is wrong.

[Magento2 Tax not displaying in Cart Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122716/magento2-tax-not-displaying-in-cart-page/122866#122866)

you will find different total value on estimation page & checkout page. Different is cart estimation page is not showing tax value in total.

[site link](http://www.guickly.com/)

use 
country - united state
state -  california
zipcode - 90001